# How can I disable/enable the button based on multiple checkboxes state in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a component on a page that renders a bunch of checkboxes and toggles.

I also have a button called `confirm` at the bottom to save the changes and make a request to update the back-end.

However I wanted to support a feature that when users haven't made any changes to any of these checkboxes or toggles, the  `confirm` button should be disabled. and when users toggle or check any of these, then the  `confirm` button is enabled and clickable.

so right now what I am doing is

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // get the current state from the store
  const state = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.settings);

  const [isCheckbox1Checked, setCheckbox1] = useState(false);
  const [isCheckbox2Checked, setCheckbox2] = useState(false);
  const [isCheckbox3Checked, setCheckbox3] = useState(false);
  const [isConfirmBtnEnabled, setConfirmBtn] = useState(false);


  const [updateBtnEnabled, enableUpdateBtn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // `getSettingsConfig` is a async thunk action
      await dispatch(getSettingsConfig());

      setCheckbox1(state.isCheckbox1Checked);

      setCheckbox2(state.isCheckbox2Checked);

      setCheckbox3(state.isCheckbox3Checked);
    })();
  }, [
    dispatch,

    state.isCheckbox1Checked,

    state.isCheckbox2Checked,

    state.isCheckbox3Checked
    // ..
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="checkboxes">
        <Checkbox1
          onCheck={() => {
            setCheckbox1(true);
            setConfirmBtn(true);
          }}
        />
        <Checkbox2
          onCheck={() => {
            setCheckbox2(true);
            setConfirmBtn(true);
          }}
        />
        <Checkbox3
          onCheck={() => {
            setCheckbox3(true);
            setConfirmBtn(true);
          }}
        />
      </div>
      <button disabled={!isConfirmBtnEnabled}>Confirm</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

right now it seems to be working out fine but it requires manually spamming `setConfirmBtn` to every checkbox and toggles I have on this page.  I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Also I thought about using `useEffect` to call `isConfirmBtnEnabled` every time any of these state changes. However since the initial state is derived from the store via dispatching an async thunk, the state of these checkboxes and toggles are going to be changed anyways after the page mounts, so that means I cannot use another `useEffect` to listen on the changes of these state.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `useEffect` hook to watch the three check boxes and update the button state based on `isConfirmBtnEnabled` which is updated inside the `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(()=>{

   setConfirmBtn(isCheckbox1Checked || isCheckbox2Checked || isCheckbox3Checked)

},[isCheckbox1Checked,isCheckbox2Checked,isCheckbox3Checked])
```

**Edit :**

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  // get the current state from the store
  const state = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.settings);

  const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({c1:false,c2:false,c3:false});
  const [isConfirmBtnEnabled, setConfirmBtn] = useState(false);


  const [updateBtnEnabled, enableUpdateBtn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // `getSettingsConfig` is a async thunk action
      await dispatch(getSettingsConfig());
  [1,2,3].forEach(i=>{
        setCheckboxes({...checkboxes,[`c${i}`]:state[`isCheckbox${1}Checked`]})
      })
    
    })();
  }, [
    dispatch,

    state
    // ..
  ]);

   useEffect(()=>{
    setConfirmBtn(Object.values(checkboxes).reduce((a,c)=>(a=a || c),false))
   },[checkboxes])
  const _onCheck=(i)=>{
 setCheckboxes({...checkboxes,[`c${i}`]:tur})
   }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="checkboxes">
        <Checkbox1
          onCheck={() => _onCheck(1)}
        />
        <Checkbox2
         onCheck={() => _onCheck(2)}
        />
        <Checkbox3
          onCheck={() => _onCheck(3)}
        />
      </div>
      <button disabled={!isConfirmBtnEnabled}>Confirm</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I actually thought of this approach but it doesn't seem to be working with my situation. sorry I didn't explain the situation clearly enough. I edited my post.

Comment: the redux `state` has only the three values (isCheckbox3Checked,isCheckbox1Checked,isCheckbox3Checked)?

Comment: no it has a lot more I am just trying to simplify it here

Comment: ok, i recommend instead of using three states for each checkboxe use one like `const [checkboxes, setCheckboxes] = useState({c1:false,c2:false,c3:false});` then in check event  `setCheckboxes({...checkboxes,c1:true})` in order to enable the button watch one dependency `checkboxes` and update `isConfirmBtnEnabled` inside the useeffect like `setConfirmBtn(checkboxes.reduce((a,c)=>(a=a || c),false))`

Comment: please check the edited answer i think you didn't understand my ugly comment above

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. could you elaborate on your second `useEffect`? I am not sure what `checkboxes.reduce((a,c)=>(a=a || c),false)` is doing. did you mean `a===a` instead of `a=a`? I am worried that the first `useEffect` which is called `setCheckboxes` will change `checkboxes` then it will trigger the second `useEffect` because of it, so the button would be enabled without users doing anything

Comment: i mean `a=a || c` `a` refers to accumulator param and `c` to current param, this sets a `||` between the array values to return a value, but i did some mistake it should be `Object.values(checkboxes).reduce....` instead of `checkboxes.reduce...`

Comment: yea I know `a` is the accumulator and `c` is the current item, but what is `a=a || c` doing here? we assign `a` to `a` and if it is falsy we return `c`? still don't understand.

Comment: it's like `a=a+1` , compare the a with c and assign that to a again